How can I JSON serialize a type that inherits from List<T> with additional properties
Anyone know how I could serialize this class using System.Text.Json
  public class MachineTray : List<MachineCoil>
  {

      public String TrayName { get; set; }

      public MachineTray() : base() { }

  }

Also doesnt help that this is just a portion of a bigger object
public class Machine 
{
    public List<MachineTray> Trays;
}

I'm serializing the object List.
JsonSerializerOptions JSO = new JsonSerializerOptions();
               
JSO.WriteIndented = true;

String JSON = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(Machines, Machines.GetType(), JSO ));

Ive been trying all sorts of combinations using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-8-0
However no matter what I try I always just get a List serialized and the TrayName property missing.

Does How can I serialize a property in an inherited ICollection class? answer your question?  You need to use a converter since, in the JSON standard, arrays cannot have properties.

Incidentally, inheriting from List<T> and adding additional properties is strongly discouraged -- not only because such types are poorly supported by serializers.  See Why not inherit from List? for why.

This type of behaviour is a known side effect and  a very strong reason why you wouldn't inherit from list.

Suggested reading: Guidelines for Collections  ...originally from 2008

It’s Microsoft who is making inheriting from List mandatory for grouping data in .net MAUI CollectionViews and ListViews. Not my choice for sure.

@MartinMcNally - that's interesting; it wouldn't be the first time that MSFT has made class libraries that are inconsistent with their own guidelines.  Out of curiosity do you have a link where they suggest to do that?

@MartinMcNally I don't see anywhere in the docs that that is the case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-8.0 what exactly is your use case?

Here is the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping?view=net-maui-8.0

Your case is quite tricky and not sure there's solution, but let's try to figure some things out:
You inherit a list and add it new property that you would like to persist in JSON. Let's first think how JSON would look like. For lists it's simple:
[ { ...item } , {... another item}, ...]

So, here the root is the array itself, we don't have root "ready to contain" more props - how would we do that?
In order to incorporate more info alongside the list, we jave two option:

add info to the root - in our case, add info to the array, so it means adding one extra item for each new property - it is extremely confusing and would mess with original array items - so this is not something we want
antother option - create root that will hold the array alongside any properties you want, so the JSON could look something like this:

{ "TrayName": "Name 051"; "Items": [ { ...object } , {... another item}, ...] }

Only the latter option in my opinion make sense.
And now, the model on C# side would look like this:
private class MachineTrayDto
{
    public string TrayName { get; set; }
    public List<MachineCoil> MachineCoils { get; set; }
}

By now it should be evident, why inheriting from List in your case is bad idea. You could use the model above.
But life is strange, and maybe this is what you want. So to handle the outlined scenario, you could use such JsonConverter:
public class MachineTrayJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MachineTray>
{
    public override MachineTray? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MachineTrayDto>(ref reader);
        var tray = new MachineTray
        {
            TrayName = dto.TrayName,
        };
        tray.AddRange(dto.MachineCoils);
        return tray;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MachineTray value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dto = new MachineTrayDto { TrayName = value.TrayName, };
        dto.MachineCoils = value;
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, dto);
    }

    private class MachineTrayDto
    {
        public string TrayName { get; set; }
        public List<MachineCoil> MachineCoils { get; set; }
    }
}


Thanks for the advice. I never wanted to inherrit from List the root object is what I had originally. However .NET MAUI makes inheriting from List mandatory to correctly group items in ListView or CollectionView. I guess what I’ll have to do is just one method for serializing and then transition to the inherited list on the device for MAUI to be happy.

@MartinMcNally So you can try my suggested solution having internal private class to handle intermediate serialization and deserialization :)
